# Cannot allocate memory for gawk coprocess

Tags: memory, fork, gawk

I have a gawk program that dies when trying to start a coprocess.  Error message is "fatal: can't open two way pipe `...' for input/output (Cannot allocate memory)".  Memory usage of the gawk process at the time of starting the coprocess is around 50%.

The gawk program is structured as follows:

```
BEGIN {    
   ## Read big file into memory -- takes about 50% of memory
   while ( (getline <"bigFile") >0) {
      list[$0]
   }
}
{
   print |& "cat"    
}
```

I assume that starting the coprocess involves a fork(), which would double memory usage, and thus cause an error?

If I force the coprocess to start before loading the file into memory, there is no problem starting the coprocess.  But the best way I know of to force the coprocess to start is to write an empty line to it:

```
print "" |& "cat"
```

And this obviously is not ideal.  (Though I can live with it, if there's no better way around this problem.)

Any ideas on cleaner solutions to this problem?

Comment: Any thoughts on this @edmorton? Thanks!